# TS2339: Property 'href' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am experiencing this problem:

I cannot access the property *href* to an HTML element.
I am getting this error:

```
Property 'href' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)
```

This is the code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'clientes-app';

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    (function($) {
        "use strict";
    
        var path = window.location.href; 
            $("#layoutSidenav_nav .sb-sidenav a.nav-link").each(function() {
                if (this.href === path) {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
            });
    
        // Toggle the side navigation
        $("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("body").toggleClass("sb-sidenav-toggled");
        });
    })(jQuery);
  }
}
```

Comment: Angular and JQuery will never be friends. `ngAfterViewInit` is a specific and useful lifecycle hook which becomes absolutely irrelevant if you use a 2008 global library and a self executing function which is now competing with Angular. Casting is the very least of your problems going forward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all `HTMLElement`s have a `href` attribute. Check if the element being currently iterated is a `HTMLAnchorElement` which has a `href` attribute, before accessing it.

```
if (this instanceof HTMLAnchorElement && this.href === path) {
     $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is the interface of the ***HTMLElement*** :

```
interface HTMLElement extends Element, DocumentAndElementEventHandlers, ElementCSSInlineStyle, ElementCSSInlineStyle, ElementContentEditable, GlobalEventHandlers, HTMLOrSVGElement {
    accessKey: string;
    readonly accessKeyLabel: string;
    autocapitalize: string;
    dir: string;
    draggable: boolean;
    hidden: boolean;
    innerText: string;
    lang: string;
    readonly offsetHeight: number;
    readonly offsetLeft: number;
    readonly offsetParent: Element | null;
    readonly offsetTop: number;
    readonly offsetWidth: number;
    spellcheck: boolean;
    title: string;
    translate: boolean;
    click(): void;
    addEventListener<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}
```

As you can see (and see the error says) it doesn't have the property *href*.
To access the **href** you have to use the interface ***HTMLAnchorElement*** (assuming your trying to access an `<a>` HTML tag, if not - see below).
The interface *HTMLAnchorElement* doesn't have the *href* property itself, but it gets from the interface *HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils* (since HTMLAnchorElement extends HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils)  that looks like this:

```
interface HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils {
    hash: string;
    host: string;
    hostname: string;
    href: string; // this is what your are looking for
    toString(): string;
    readonly origin: string;
    password: string;
    pathname: string;
    port: string;
    protocol: string;
    search: string;
    username: string;
}
```

Not every HTML element has the *href* attribute.
In the answer, I have assumed that you are accessing an anchor tag.
But, as far as I am aware of, the following HTML elements might have the *href* property:

```
<a>, <link>, <area>, <base>.
```

So you might use those interfaces respectively: HTMLAnchorElement, HTMLLinkElement, HTMLAreaElement, HTMLBaseElement.

Comment: To explain further, `each` is being applied to a collection `HTMLElement`s. So the `this` in `this.href` refers to an `HTMLElement`. Not every HTML element in a page has an href, so, naturally, the `HTMLElement` type isn't going to have an `href` property. But a type like `HTMLAnchorElement` will.

Comment: Nice well detailed answer, but I think he just has a bunch of `<a>`s in a `<nav>` navbar `$("#layoutSidenav_nav .sb-sidenav a.nav-link")`

Comment: thanks, I think so too. Just wanted to leave a mention also for the other HTML tags that might have an href property in case someone in the future googles for this issue

Comment: Please do not translate non-English questions. They're off-topic on Stack Overflow and must be closed with reason "Needs clarity" or "Not suitable..."